# appear modal windows bottom

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5

I have this modal windows in my application, this work fine

```
 <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

But when the modal appears, this appear for the top of my windows, and I want to appear for the bottom

The application is a joomla 3.0! and I using a template of [Meet Gavern](http://www.gavick.com/joomla-templates/meet-gavern,93.html)

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I modified  de css in Bootstrap

```
.modal.fade {

  top:-25%;
  -webkit-transition:opacity .3s linear, bottom .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:opacity .3s linear, bottom .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:opacity .3s linear, bottom .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition:opacity .3s linear, bottom .3s ease-out;
  transition:opacity .3s linear, bottom .3s ease-out;
}
```